# Hadoop MapReduce Word Counting Example

Tags: algorithms, parallel-computing, cluster

[image]

In an example of the application of MapReduce provided by University of Utah, it says that Map() function emits <"hello", 1> every time it sees hello where the reduce function counts the number of instances "hello" occurs

My question is if this is the case, why isn't reduce doing <"hello", {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1...}>, where each 1 is an instance Map() emits a key,value pair? In the example it wrote something like <"hello", (3,5,2,7)>, what does it mean?

Also, why do you need MapReduce to do this? I can just use an linked list on my computer.

Thanks

Comment: "Also, why do you need MapReduce to do this? I can just use an linked list on my computer."
Of course you dont *need* MapReduce for this or anything else, just as you don't *need* to use a linked list instead. It's just an example and, since it's an example for teaching, it's deliberately a simple example.

Comment: This is a programming question, not a computer *science* question. I'm not sure whether you'd want it on [SO] or maybe [scicomp.SE], but it's definitely offtopic here.

Comment: @Raphael, might the programmers stack exchange also be a good fit? It seems more conceptual than the code-related questions I'm accustomed to seeing on SO. (I agree it doesn't really fit here.)

Comment: @SeanEaster I don't think so, but I'm not an expert of the scope of either site. The question here is essentially "please explain this code" which should imho be ontopic on [SO].

Comment: @Raphael Fair interpretation, and a sound enough reason to migrate, from my view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [...] it says that Map() function emits <"hello", 1> every time it sees hello where the reduce function counts the number of instances "hello" occurs

Not quite: It appears the mapper reads each file, counts the number of times a word appears, and outputs a single `(word, count)` pair per *file*, rather than per occurrence of the word. The reduce step then sums these. `("hello", 1)` indicates that "hello" appeared once in a given file, `("hello", 3)` indicates three appearances in a file, etc.

In the example for the reduce step, it appears four files were mapped, and that "hello" appeared 3 times in the first, 5 in the second, etc.

> Also, why do you need MapReduce to do this?

Via [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) MapReduce is "for processing parallelizable problems across huge datasets using a large number of computers[.]" Meaning, if your task is to count the number of times "hello" appears in four small documents, you likely don't need MapReduce. But if your task is to count the appearances of *all* words that appear in a large set of documents, then the only way to accomplish this is a practically useful time may require distributing across multiple processors.